# Can't autowire Mapper object in Spring's StoredProcedure implementation with Cursor OUT variable, must construct manually instead

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We use Row Mappers in both plain-SQL DAO fetches and Spring's `StoredProcedure` implementations.

If we have a Row Mapper defined as

```
@Component
public class MyMapper implements RowMapper<MyEntry> {

    @Override
    public MyEntry mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        //...
        return new MyEntry(..);
    }
}
```

it can be correctly autowired and used in plain-SQL fetches to bring back a `List<MyEntry>` as

```
@Autowired
private MyMapper myMapper;

return jdbcNamedParameterTemplate.query(SQL, myMapper);
```

But in the case of a Spring's `StoredProcedure` implementation, the Mapper can't be autowired, and manual construction with `private RowMapper<MyEntry> rowMapper = new MyMapper();` seems to be required. Otherwise, if we try to autowire as below,

```
@Component
public class MySP extends StoredProcedure {

    @Autowired
    private MyMapper rowMapper;

    public MySP(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, "MY_STORED_PROC");
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("P_REF_CURSOR", OracleTypes.REF_CURSOR, rowMapper));
        compile();
    }
}
```

the list returned is **not** a `List<MyEntry>`, but a `List<LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap>`. I do not believe that the Mapper was ever invoked, so maybe it was skipped entirely. Any further operations on the collection result in the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap cannot be cast to class app.MyEntry
```